# If I complement the address, I have the previous command append in sed

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sed

I have this file:

```
$ cat ciao 
ciao
ciao
ciii
ciaooo
ocisdjoo
kdvkks
kdafjdjf
akfk
```

and

```
$ sed ciao -n -e "1,3p"
ciao
ciao
ciii
$ sed ciao -n -e "1,3!p"
sed ciao -n -e "1,3ps -aux | grep nano"
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: extra characters after command
$
```

If I press arrow up to see the previous command:

```
$ sed ciao -n -e "1,3ps -aux | grep nano"
```

WHY??

Shouldn't I see:

```
ciaooo
ocisdjoo
kdvkks
kdafjdjf
akfk
```

If I use a sed filter, it works!

```
$ sed -n -f filter.sed
```

where filter.sed is simply:

```
1,3!p
```

Comment: That csh-style history expansion. Use single quotes instead of double quotes. You may want to disable history expansion if you're not using it.

Comment: thanks a lot :)

Comment: The question I've marked this as a duplicate of does not deal with `sed`, but it has the exact same issue and symptom. The best approach for you would likely be to single quotes in place of double quotes around the `sed` editing expression.